# Making a column reference 2 columns from separate tables laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, foreign-keys, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to take 2 tables that both have columns called `email` `password` and `isBusiness` and auto update those values in one table called `authentication`

**Authentication migration**

```
Schema::create('authentication', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('auth_id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->foreign('email')->references('email')->on('businesses');
        $table->foreign('email')->references('email')->on('consumers');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->foreign('password')->references('password')->on('businesses');
        $table->foreign('password')->references('password')->on('consumers');
        $table->integer('isBusiness');
        $table->foreign('isBusiness')->references('isBusiness')->on('businesses');
        $table->foreign('isBusiness')->references('isBusiness')->on('consumers');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Error**

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `sprout_db`.`#sql-2
  7a4_30` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

**Business Table**

```
Schema::create('businesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('bus_id', 11);
        $table->string('bus_name', 50);
        $table->string('bus_address', 50);
        $table->string('bus_city', 50);
        $table->string('bus_prov', 50);
        $table->string('bus_postal', 50);
        $table->string('bus_phone', 50);
        $table->string('email', 50);
        $table->string('password', 100);
        $table->integer('isBusiness')->default('1');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
```

**Consumer Table**

```
Schema::create('consumers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('con_id', 11);
            $table->string('con_fname', 50);
            $table->string('con_lname', 50);
            $table->string('email', 50);
            $table->string('password', 100);
            $table->integer('isBusiness')->default('0');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });
```

is this the proper way of doing it? By assigning 2 foreign keys to each column? Do I just have a syntax error or is this not even possible to do this way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel, but it looks to me like you're trying to make a single field reference a corresponding field in two different tables? While that is possible, it is pretty much never a good idea.

Comment: That said... it looks like you probably need to stop trying to make the varchar fields "unsigned". ;)

Comment: I removed unsigned. then it gave ma an error which I was able to fix. I'm not getting a new error about the way I am assigning the foreign keys. I've updated the question

Comment: You have to index the fields referenced by the foreign key (and they have to exist, so the tables referenced must be created first); but I as I said in the original comment, having one field reference multiple tables is usually a very bad idea. In case you're thinking it means "must match a value in tableA or tableB", it does not; it means the value must exist in BOTH tables (and depending on reference options, could "cascade" changes from either).

Answer (score 0):

Just add index() method to your key.

```
    $table->integer('isBusiness')->index()->unsigned();
```

Comment: why would I add `index()` and `unsigned()` to it?

Comment: I tried it without success. I just wanted to know the reasoning behind it.

Comment: because a foreign key integer must be and index on his table and unsigned

Comment: so on all tables the key must be indexed and unsigned? or just the authentication table?

Comment: @Jay typically, foreign keys are not created on string values; it is allowed, but relatively expensive compared to integers. The unsigned part is not required (even for integers), but the fields referenced by a foreign key must be indexed.